# Long titles are being cut (with ...) in Appixia app blocks view

Tags: shopping-cart, appixia

I have an Appixia app and I'm creating a carousel of products. Each product (item) in the carousel is implemented using the `GenericStaticBlocksCellView` \ `DynamicBlocksView` module

I've added the product titles by creating a block of type `Text` and specifying Field = `Title`

I've also given the block width and height, the height is big enough to fit several lines, but if my titles are too long, they are just cut off at the end (and a ... appears).

How can I fix my long titles so all the text appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, text blocks only show a single line of text. So it your titles don't fit in a single line, they will be shortened, no matter how tall your block is.

You can override this behavior by using the `MultiLine` property of the block. Set it to `true` and then your text will span several lines.

Make sure the block is tall enough (using the `Height` property) to hold all of the lines that you need